# Error on menu navigator routing

Tags: zend-framework, routes, navigator

I make navigator through XML navigation file, and I specify the default action for each item in the menu. When I create custom routing for all others routes in the system the navigator is not working correctly, it takes the routing from the URL ?!!

Does it have any relation between navigators and custom routing?

Here's where I initialize the navigator

```
protected function _initNavigation() {
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
    $view->navigation($navigation);


}
```

**EDIT**

```
  <visits>
        <label>Visits</label>
        <module>visits</module>
        <controller>visit</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <route>visits/visit/index</route>
    </visits>
```

and I make routing in application.ini

```
;routing
resources.router.routes.visit.route = /visits
resources.router.routes.visit.defaults.module = visits
resources.router.routes.visit.defaults.controller = visit
resources.router.routes.visit.defaults.action = index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `<route>` (untested, but should work according to documentation):

```
<controller>index</controller>
<action>index</action>
<route>yourRouteName</route>
```

Comment: This error occur Fatal error: Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route visits/visit/index is not defined

Comment: I think you entered the route path, you should enter the route **name**

Comment: Do you mean the name of the custom route?? if yes, I did the same error!

Comment: I make it through writing    <route>visits</route> thank you :)